# DNN access elements between different ascx files c#

Tags: c#, dotnetnuke

I am trying to develop a custom module where I want with a checkbox in the Settings.ascx to enable/disable a button in Edit.ascx. Is that possible and if it is how can I access the button in Edit from the settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, just like you would in the view

```
var val = Settings["settingName"];
```

Or maybe I'm not understanding.  The Edit screen and the Settings screen shouldn't be visible at the same time so how would one screen access the other?  The only thing you can do is access the same data.

Answer (score 0):

Create a module setting named "ActivateButton" in settings.ascx and save it.

In Edit.ascx, retrieve and use that setting to enable/disable the button.